# Why do red-black trees with have height at most 2 * O(ln N + 1)?

Tags: tree, time-complexity, red-black-tree

A red-black tree with n internal nodes has height at most 2 * O(ln N + 1). In other words, red-black trees have height at most twice optimal.

Can anyone explain why is this the case intuitively? I am not looking for inductive proofs (I can find them online). Just an intuitive reason why this is the case? I can't come up with an example where a R-B tree has height at most 2 * O(ln N + 1).

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-10-red-black-trees-rotations-insertions-deletions/lec10.pdf) gives an intuitive proof to the theorem.

Below, I will simply go over the steps of the proof:

1. Merge the red nodes to their black parents and get a new tree.
2. Resulting tree will have nodes branching 2, 3, or 4 child.
3. Observation: new tree's black height h' is going to be the same as the black height of the original tree.
4. Observation: new tree's height h' can be at least half of the height of the original tree h. (i.e. we have h' >= h/2)
5. A complete binary tree with height h' has 2^h' -1 internal nodes.

   - remember step 2, our new tree is branching 2,3, or 4 in internal nodes.
   - thus, number of internal nodes of new tree is more than 2^h' -1
   - the original tree has even more internal nodes than the new tree (since we merged the red nodes to heir black parents). Thus, n >= 2^h' -1
6. the rest is algebra:

   - n+1 >= 2^h' (take logarithm of both sides)
   - lg(n+1) >= h' (we know that h' >= h/2 from step 4 above)

Finally we get

- 2lg(n+1) >= h.

This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Another intuitive reasoning why H is upper-bounded by 2LogN: The RB Tree has a property that each Path must have same number of Black Nodes, meaning that if a Path has 7 Black Nodes, including Nil but excluding the Root, each Path must have this number of Black Nodes or we will rebalance the Tree to maintain the property. H is the height of the largest path of the Tree and if the Tree only have Black Nodes it will be 7 here. But it's quite unlikely as Tree will have some number of Red Nodes.

More Red Nodes we have more the height will be, but we can have at most 7 Red Nodes in that largest path. There the H will be 14 for this example and Black Nodes will be at least H/2. Here we will have an interesting case, the Sub Tree of this Red Black Tree creating by cutting of the tree at H/2 will be a Complete Binary Search Tree, why? Because even if a Path has all the Black Nodes it must have 7 of them, and if some path has some Red Nodes they will be bigger than 7 in their heights so at this cutoff, we will get a Complete Binary Search Tree.

This Sub Tree has Nodes = 2^H/2 - 1, so we can say that total number of nodes, N, in the RB Tree will be N>= 2^H/2 - 1. Taking the logs and doing remaining algebra we can get Theta(2LogN) as the upper bound of the height of the Red Black Tree.